# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^p} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Investigate the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^p}$. For what values of p does the series converge?
I have applied the ratio test, which is inconclusive. Would Cauchy Condensation help? How would this be approached otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^p}=\frac{1}{n^p(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{2(n+1)^{p+1/2}}\le\frac{1}{n^p(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\le \frac{1}{n^{p+1/2}}.
$$
Comparison test with $\,\dfrac{1}{n^a}\,$ provides that the series converges iff $$
p+\frac{1}{2}>1 \quad\text{or equivalently} \quad p>1/2.
$$

Comment: Didn't you miss a $2$ in the denominator of the most right term of the inequalities ?

Comment: The inequality holds with or without this 2.

Comment: Yes, for sure !! It was just making a closer bound and symmetry. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^p}=\frac1{n^p\cdot(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\sim\frac1{n^p\cdot2\sqrt{n}}=\frac{c}{n^{p+1/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try a comparison test after writing
$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{n^p}=\frac1{n^p(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$. From this we see that the series converges iff $p > \dfrac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Since you already received good answers, let me just consider the behavior of the general term when $n$ is large $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}-\frac{1}{8}
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2}\right)$$ from which it is clear that $p \gt \frac{1}{2}$ is the requirement.

Comment: I would like to understand the asymptotic argument. How is this expansion accomplished? How does it support the conclusion that p>1/2?

Comment: Factor $\sqrt n$ first and set $x=1/n$; you are left with $\sqrt {1+x}-1$  with $x$ being small. Use Taylor expansion for $x$ and come back to $n$.