# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^p}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My guess was it depends on $p$. So I converted it to $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{p+0.5}(\sqrt{1+\frac {1}{n}}+\sqrt1)}$ by multiplying the numerator by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ and taking out $n^{0.5}$ from the denominator.

I am not sure how to get rid of $\sqrt{1+\frac {1}{n}}+\sqrt 1$ in the denominator to use the theorem which says $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{p+0.5}}$ diverges when p<0.5 and converges p>0.5. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! What is $a_n$?

Comment: that was a mistake. just fixed it

Comment: It converges when $p$ is greater than $1\frac 12$ use  $2\sqrt n <\sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt n < 3\sqrt n$ when $n$ is not very small.  Then set up comparison tests.

Comment: I suggest you drop the $n=0$ summand and start at $n=1$.

Comment: Your multiplication factor of $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ has the wrong sign. It should be $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: the function in the title had the wrong sign. My bad

Comment: The sum has to start at $n=1$. Besides that, asymptotic comparison with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{p+1/2}}$ trivially gives that the given series is convergent iff $p>1/2$, as already stated.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how can I show that if I haven`t learned asymptotic comparison? I cannot evoke the theorem because I have some other terms in the denominator. thank you

Comment: @KaanYolsever: are you able to bound $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ between $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for any $n\geq 1$? If so, you do not need anything else.

Comment: Some other related posts: [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/977839), [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{n^p}$ for $p \ge 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1515799), [Convergence for $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1524439), [Determine for which $x$ the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^x}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2132354), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find an *equivalent* of the general term: $\;\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\sim_\infty2\sqrt n$, so
$$ \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{n^p}=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)n^p}\sim_\infty\frac 2{\sqrt n \,n^{p}}=\frac 2{n^{p+\tfrac12}}, $$
which converges if and only if $\;p+\tfrac12>1$.

Comment: the term i first used had the wrong sign. the correct one is $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @KaanYolsever: I've  updated myswer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean by finding an equivalent? I understand the intuition but is there a way to put it more rigorously?

Comment: @KaanYolsever: Roughly speaking, two functions $f$ and $g$ are equivalent in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ if $\;\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)/g(x)=1$. It is a concept from *Asymptotic Analysis*  which can simplify greatly the determination of limits.